# Cannot create new package in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, integration

I am trying to create API integration with Marketing Cloud.
According to following instructions [Create and Install Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm)
first step is to click on new and create new package. But i do not have new button. I am using Development Community account and I am an Administrator. Please help 
[image]

Comment: I assume you want to integrate Marketing Cloud with Sales Cloud, is this correct?

Comment: Not really. I want to integrate product that is developed by company I am working in with Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Do you have login credentials for Marketing Cloud? This screen shot looks as it is from Sales Cloud

Comment: No I do not have one. As you noticed in one of my questions, I have confused Marketing Cloud and SalesForce. I am currently trying to contact MC to get the access.

Answer (score 0):

Log into SFMC. Into the correct business unit.

Navigate to Settings (under your username) > Admin

Then Account > Installed Packages  Then you can create a new package.

You may need additional permissions to do this.

[image]